# Cors definition in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, cors, sinatra

I'm building a simple app using Ruby and Sinatra and  was looking for a sample CORS config, and I found this:

```
before do
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Accept, Authorization, Origin'
end

options '*' do
  response.headers['Allow'] = 'HEAD, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, POST'
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept'
end
```

It works correctly but I wanted to go more into details. The `options` `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` are different from the others in the `before` block. 
I was wondering if they make reference to the `options` itself or have a reason behind it? I'm not sure if they should be the same.

Comment: You're using any gem for this?

Answer (score 4):

The `options` block mainly serves as a [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). It tells the client what headers/methods are allow before actually making the actual HTTP request.

As for the `before` block, I believe you only need to set the `Allow Origin`, unless you use different configuration for different endpoint.